# why can't we use #define preprocessor's constant before it's declaration

Tags: c++

If `#define` is a preprocessor directive then the compiler will know before the actual compilation what that constant is as it is defined already but it does give error if we use before it. Here's the code I want to run:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void sum(){
    cout<<"PI is: "<<pi;
}
#define pi 3
void main(){
    sum();
}
```

This gives error like:

> undefined symbol pi

According to theory the (#) statements will be compiled first so the compiler already knows what pi is.

Comment: The preprocessor is defined to run top-to-bottom, *then* hand its output to the compiler. The use of `pi` in your code happens before the preprocessor knows about it, so it doesn't replace it, and the compiler chokes on it.

Comment: Also, `main` returns `int`, not `void`.

Comment: When the preprocessor encounters the first `pi`, it is not defined as a macro, so it is not changed.  Only after the `#define` line will the preprocessor treat `pi` as a macro.  This is very important.  (Also, you can't use variables before they're declared.)

Comment: But the #define line is compiled first so it must know what pi is

Comment: Don't use preprocessor constants at all. Use `const double pi = 3.14;`

Comment: @DarshanGupta if you put the `#define` in its proper place, the compiler *never* sees `pi`. It sees the `3` that the preprocessor left instead.

Comment: @DarshanGupta: if #define` could replace text "above" itself, Then what would `#undef` do?

Comment: @manni66 everyone recommends using #define instead of const

Comment: `But the #define line is compiled first` - no, it isn't.

Comment: No one recommends #define instead of const.

Comment: and @Quentin I can't understand please tell it again briefly

Comment: "everyone recommends using #define instead of const"  - like who, for example - every book on C++ suggests not using `#define`, and indeed the semantics of `const` were designed by Stroustrup to replace it.

Comment: @neilButterworth then which line is compiled first?

Comment: The first  line  in the iostream header..

Comment: Ok I have one more question..

Comment: Do #define constants have memory space for housing themselves?

Comment: "Do #define constants have memory space for housing themselves?" - no, any more than `5` or `42` does.

Comment: @NeilButterworth the #define is among the starting lines, basically before the function definition

Comment: #define replaces text, nothing else.

Comment: "e #define is among the starting lines, basically before the function definition" - NO IT ISN'T! It's the 6th line in that code.

Comment: The preprocessor simply processes the file from top to bottom, replacing the `#define` with the text equilivant. The #define is removed from the text. The resulting text is then compiled.

Comment: .... does it compile after the sum() definition? @neil

Comment: It doesn't compile at all. The `#define` says that  FROM THIS POINT IN THE CODE, replace all occurrences of `pi` with `3`. When all such substitutions have been made, the resulting text is handed to the compiler for compilation.

Comment: Ok then this just tells the compiler to do this. But when does it? after the sum() func. or before?

Comment: Firstly, in modern C++ you should probably prefer `constexpr` over `#define` or `const`. Secondly, if/when you are writing cross-compilable C/C++ code, then it shoudl be `#define`, not `const`.

Comment: by the way why do we use #define (and not constants) statements in resource files while building gui based apps

Comment: @Darshan Gupta: Firstly, C++ language does not have the concept of "resource files", so it is not clear what you are talking about. Secondly, your "resource files" might be intended for inclusion in C code. C `const` is very different from C++ `const`. In C you have to use `#define`, not `const` in general case.

Comment: A compelling reason for it to work top down is that you can `#undef` a preceding `#define`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because macros are treated in a "top down" manner.

[cpp.replace]

> A preprocessing directive of the form 
>   `# define identifier replacement-list new-line`
>   defines an object-like macro that causes each **subsequent instance** of the macro name to be replaced by the
>   replacement list of preprocessing tokens that constitute the remainder of the directive

They last until a corresponding `#undef` is encountered, or the end of the translation unit (source file), whichever comes first (cpp.scope])

Comment: by the way why do we use #define (and not constants) statements in resource files while building gui based apps

Comment: @DarshanGupta: Oftentimes people use them because they don't take up any additional memory, whereas constant variables do.

Comment: Sorry 2 years ago I didn't know how to upvote and approve a answer. Didn't view my profile page since then. So sorry for the late approvement